# Is there a way to password protect a directory with .htaccess and have it remember the password?

Tags: linux, .htaccess

My experience is that using .htAccess to password protect a directory, it brings up a modal dialog box. And for some browsers (FF and Chrome) don't show the checkbox for "remember" this password.

Is there a way to that a password protect a directory and have the user fill in the username and password within the web page?

Or, is there a way to force the browser to remember that password?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: No.

We are talking about something called [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Unfortunately, [these things are features of the browser, and cannot be controlled from the server side](http://apache.active-venture.com/auth-basic.html#basicfaq). Some browsers have the ability to remember your password forever (usually in the form of a "remember my password" checkbox). It is debatable whether this is a good idea, but at least the user makes the call; forcing this choice from the server side is really a bad idea and I don't think any browser would allow that. Why? The user probably don't want to store his credentials if using a shared device (for example, in a public library).

That said, using an Apache .htaccess file is not the only way to do basic authentication. Using any dinamic content framework (PHP, ASP, etc), you can store a session cookie after the user has authenticated and only send the 401 response and basic authentication headers if the user has no authentication cookie. Since you talk about .htaccess, I assume you are on a LAMP stack; take a look at:

- Basic authentication: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php
- Sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php